# How to create auto-update dependent dropdown list?

Tags: dropdown

I have a great task with creating auto-updating dependent dropdown list. I have a long list of fruits and long list of vegetables, which again may keep adding. So the reference dropdown would be selecting fruits or vegetables.The dependent dropdown should have the list of the previous selection. The problem here is the list gets updated so often, so I cannot give any fixed reference of the list. Also the list of fruits need not be the length of the list of vegetables, which when including a fixed reference column leads to the display of zeros in the drop-down taking into account the empty cells.

Please help me through this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi Tarasovych, I havent tried any code, but I have used data validation with the formula '=OFFSET('LIST'!$A$1,1,MATCH($D$2,'LIST'!$A$1:$B$1,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET('LIST'!$A$1,1,MATCH($D$2,'LIST'!$A$1:$B$1,0)-1,100,1)),1)'